# How to Instantiate a generic class with the given type when given type is an Array

Tags: java, generics

say i have these classes:

```
class B<T> {}

class A<T> {

}
```

Instantiating A:

```
A<Float[]> a = new A<>();
```

In A's constructor I want to initialize B class with the type of T but not as an Array

```
B<Float> b = new B<>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more details, I'm not 100% sure this can work, but:

Change the generic type argument of A to be just `Float`, not `Float[]`. Then, on A's methods that take/return `T`, change them to specify `T[]`.

If that doesn't work for you, your alternatives are:
* use reflection (somewhat pointless, as generic type enforcement is compile-time only in Java)
* use compatible superclasses and casting (syntax fairly obnoxious, and you'll get little to no help from the compiler)
* use plain, unparameterized types (syntax is fine, still no help from the compiler)

If you edit your question to include more details, I'm happy to edit this to provide more specific guidance.

Comment: Your first recommendation was the first thing that came to my mind, unfortunately that would result in many hours of code refactoring and logic changing. I actually solved my problem with a 'naive' way. I removed type parameter and I implemented the methods set/get/logic with Object, and in the constructor I pass a class that i use to cast by objects.